# como trabalhar com tabela Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html5

Observem a figura

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para deixar a data ao lado da palavra Dólar?

Esse é o código!

```
<div class="row">
        12/12/2000
    </div>
        <div class="row">
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td v-for="(moeda, key, index) in bancodedados.valores" :key="index">{{moeda.nome}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td v-for="(valor, key, index) in bancodedados.valores" :key="index">R$ {{valor.valor}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Se eu fizer essa tentativa a pagina quebra;

```
<div class="row">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">12/12/2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td v-for="(moeda, key, index) in bancodedados.valores" :key="index">{{moeda.nome}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td v-for="(valor, key, index) in bancodedados.valores" :key="index">R$ {{valor.valor}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Numa nova coluna?

Comment: Se eu colocar numa nova coluna não vai alterar nada, fica a mesma coisa.

Comment: Já tentou colocar uma coluna na primeira TR com rowspan: `<td rowspan="2">12/12/2000</td>`

Comment: eu atualizei a pagina, dá uma olhada, a pagina quebrou

Comment: Não era dessa forma que falei, era colocar a TD dentro da TR onde aparece o dolar.

Comment: ficou perfeito, muito obrigado, pode posta como sugestão certa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode criar uma coluna dentro da primeira linha e usar `rowspan` que irá mesclar a primeira coluna nas duas primeiras linhas:

```
<div class="row">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">12/12/2000</td>
        <td v-for="(moeda, key, index) in bancodedados.valores" :key="index">{{moeda.nome}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td v-for="(valor, key, index) in bancodedados.valores" :key="index">R$ {{valor.valor}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer desta maneira, pois deverá funcionar.

```
<div class="row">
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">12/12/2000</td>
    <td v-for="(moeda, key, index) in bancodedados.valores" :key="index">
{{moeda.nome}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td v-for="(valor, key, index) in bancodedados.valores" :key="index">R$ 
{{valor.valor}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>

</tr>
</table>
```